# PostgreSQL database should require user password to access, but does not

Tags: postgresql, table-plus

I created a user with a password for a database and granted SELECT/INSERT/etc. rights for that user on that db.
However, when I connect to the database with the particular user, e.g. with TablePlus, the password is not required to connect to it. I feel like this is not secure, I would prefer the connection to require the user password.

How should I change it?

I use PostgreSQL 12.1 and TablePlus Build 282.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if you are doing this locally it won't, you need to change the auth settings in pg_hba for that. Try it remotely and it WILL ask for the password.

Comment: @RajVerma has a point: most likely you have a `trust` entry in your `pg_hba.conf` file ;)

Comment: Thank you both! So I should not touch the pg_hba.conf file, right?